# How to define a lambda expression without both std::function and auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have read the item31 of "Effective Modern C++" and web page of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda and wonder if I can define a lambda by its definite type instead of the wrapped type of std::function or keyword of `auto` and how can I accomplish that.

for instance, for the type `int`:

```
auto x_1 = 5; // type deduction
int x_2 = 5;  // defined by definite type
// both x_1, x_2 are int variables of value 5
```

now, when the problem comes to the lambda:

```
auto f_1_0 = []()->int{return 5;};
std::function<int(void)> f_1_1 = []()->int{return 5;};
SomeType f_2 = []()->int{return 5;}; // what's the SomeType here?
```

Comment: Lambda's have unutterable type names. Their types have to be deduced.

Comment: If you want a concrete type name build a functor.  Lambdas are meant to be anonymous.

Comment: Technically you can, i.e. by re-implementing `std::function`, but as your actual question appears to be whether you can discover the lambda's typename: That you can't do.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the name of the lambda.  If you just want to see what the compiler came up with, you can use `print_T<decltype(lambda)>()` where `template <typename T> print_T() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }`.

Comment: @Henri "__PRETTY_FUNCTION__"  is not a standard thing. Gcc, right?  (I admire your ability to get this editor to display __PRETTY_FUNCTION___ correctly.)

Comment: @JiveDadson `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is non-standard, but it's available in GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each lambda expression has its own unique type.

Here the expressions f_1 and f2 have different types.

```
auto f_1 = []()->int {return 5; }; 
auto f_2 = []()->int {return 5; };
```

Assigning f_2 = f_1 is illegal.

The standard says the types are "unnamed." In practice, the compiler probably makes up a new, hiiden typename for each lambda. Visual C++17 gave them the following names.

```
classmain::<lambda_7e9d7fb093569d78a8c871761cbb39d7>
classmain::<lambda_8f061a3967cd210147d6a4978ab6e125>
```

Not very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says that the type of the lambda is *unnamed* so the implementation creates a implementation defined name it uses similar to the other unnamed classes, structs enumc etc.

> **ISO C++: 5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]**
>
> 3 The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, *unnamed* non-union class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below.

The standard also says that the lambda 'behaves like a function' so you it could be used with the `std::function` template:

> [Note: A closure object behaves like a function object (20.9).—end note]

And if you really want to have names for your can use the old-fashioned [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) and do all the work the compiler do for you with the [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 1):

in some cases you can use *function pointers* (using mvcpp, 0x17):

```
auto usingAuto = []() {
    cout << "autoMagick" << endl;
};
void(*pureCpp)() = []() {
    cout << "pureCpp" << endl;
};

//pureCpp = usingAuto; //you can even assing function pointers from lambdas
//usingAuto = pureCpp;  //error
pureCpp();
usingAuto();
```